# How can I transpose multiple columns at once?

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I am trying to transpose three columns by two variables.

My current dataset looks like:

```
 Person     Date    Company      Industry       Number 
  John      2017     Apple       Tech            5
  John      2017    Starbucks    Beverages       3
   Kim      2014      Hilton     Hotels          9
```

I would like my output data set to look like:

```
 Person | Date | Company1 | Industry1 | Number1 | Company2 |Industry2| Number2

  John  | 2017 |  Apple   |   Tech    |  5      | Starbucks| Beverage| 3
  Kim   | 2014 |   Hilton |  Hotels   |  9      |     -    |    -    |  -
```

As you can see, I would like each observation to be unique by name and date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question has been asked several times before.  Here's an example you can modify (you'll need to add a `class` statement for person and date)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130605/how-do-you-make-a-table-into-one-long-row-in-sas/49132603#49132603

Comment: There's a really good macro and write up here of an approach. You need to download the paper and code, but it will do exactly what you want. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Better_Way_to_Flip_(Transpose)_a_SAS_Dataset